# I don't understand why the border attribute is not working

Tags: html, css

```
<pre>
  <head>
    <style>
       body{
        background-color: blue;
       }
      .a
      {
        background-color: white;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
         border-color: white;
         border-style: solid;
         border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        border-color: black;
        border-radius: 2px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="a">
      <h1>SignUp</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</pre>
```

I don't understand why the border attribute does not work please explain to me.
(I removed the base tags because the website says there is too much code).

Comment: its working whats the problem

Comment: Look at Aditya Prakash's answer

Comment: yeah i saw that but i thought thats not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```
border-color: white;
border-color: black;
```

You are setting border-color twice.

[image]

Setting the same property twice is a very bad practice. Once you remove either one of them, the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you write 2 times same code

```
border-color: white;
border-radius: 10px;
border-color: black;
border-radius: 2px;
```

the client(web browser) will replace first code with last code, the client will run last code where

```
border-color: black;
border-radius: 2px;
```

you can remove each one of them or you can use

```
border: [size] [style] [color];
```

example :

```
border: 10px solid black;
```

to avoid repeat in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this??

```css
 body
    {
     background-color: blue;
    }

    div.border
    {
     background-color: white;
     display: block;
     margin: auto;
     border: 5px solid black;
     border-style: solid;
     border-radius: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     width: 400px;
     height: 600px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="border">SignUp</div>
```